# find density function from moment generating function

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

I'm suppose to obtain the density function of this mgf for a discrete random variable $Y$ taking values in range $[0, \infty)$, where $E(e^{ty}) = e^{-l}[1-e^t(1-p)]^{-ld},c\in \mathbb{R}^+,p \in [0,1]$.

My intuition was to find the taylor polynomial of this function but it quickly blew into a incomprehensible mess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) expansion, we have

\begin{align}
e^{-\lambda}[1-e^t(1-p)]^{-\lambda c} &= e^{-\lambda }\left[1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(-\lambda c - j)}{k!} (-e^t(1-p))^k\right]
\end{align}

Now, we just have to read off the coefficient of $e^{tk}$:

$$Pr(Y=k) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{(1-p)^k}{k!}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(\lambda c + j)$$

Comment: sorry, can you please be more elaborate, I don't see how the 1st part becomes the 2nd and how you removed the 1 inside the bracket  for the 3rd step

Comment: hi, i use [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), the $1$ is not removed, it corresponds to the case when $k=0$.